# What is the difference between CPU Retention Bracket and CPU Backplate?

Tags: cpu, computer-building

For AMD-Built Computers: What is the difference between the two, their purpose and are there different types of CPU Retention Brackets and CPU Back plates?

Do you always need a CPU Back plate? In what cases do you need them and not need them?

In what order would you install the following onto the case?:

- Motherboard
- CPU (+thermal paste)
- CPU Back plate
- CPU Retention Bracket

Answer (score 1):

The retention bracket is the bracket on the front of the motherboard where you put your CPU in. Also known as the CPU Socket. It has a special lever to keep the CPU in place.

The backplate is on the other side of the motherboard, the back side of the motherboard. This plate is used for 2 things.

1. To attach the screws for the cooler
2. To get heat from the other side of the motherboard transfered to the cooler as well.

So yes, you really do need the back plate as well, if the cooler you got requires it. The backplate is part of the cooler. It is common for motherboards to give a backplate, and then the cooler using that. It is also common that the cooler comes with their own backplate, then you use the backplate that comes with the cooler.

The order of operations may slightly differ per cooler, so it is best to follow the instructions that come with the cooler itself. You can install the CPU first though. I recommend not installing the motherboard into the case before the CPU and cooler are in place onto the motherboard.